# Android : How to detect the device is Huawei or not?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to find a way to detect whether the device is Huawei or not.
My app has a piece of code that causes a crash on Huawei devices, I want to avoid executing that code if the device is Huawei.

I don't want to use checks based on GMS & HMS availability cause my app does not contain dependency for these packages.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. The Code standard is poor, but it gets the job done. I don't think Huawei will ever change its name.

```
private boolean isHuaweiDevice(){
    String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String brand =  android.os.Build.BRAND;
    return  manufacturer.toLowerCase().contains("huawei") ||  brand.toLowerCase().contains("huawei");
}
```